# Pretty simple initialization question, I hope

Tags: json, swift, parsing, data-binding, initialization

I'm a little new to the swift world and am having a little confusion with how to properly initialize and track changes to some of my variables.

I had this thing running great off of local data. Now that I brought in the same data from a Json file it blew up.

I'm bringing in a two sets of data from JSON files.(No problem parsing that.) The issue came when I created a copy of the data(so I can preserve its state). I need to be able to track when the user modifies the data then compare the updated data to its original state. Anyway, my issue feels rather simple.

I am comparing two instances of my custom class. One is initialized with the json data. The second is a copy of the first instance that changes over the course of several views.

...

```
let myWandsImport: [Wand] =  load("myWandData.json")
let someWandsImport: [Wand] = load("someWandData.json")

struct AccountView: View {
    // Declare Variables
    @Binding var myWand: Wand
    @Binding var someWands: [Wand]
    @Binding var myWands: [Wand]

    let backgroundImage = "Parchment Background"
    
    init() {
        myWands = myWandsImport
        myWand = myWandsImport[0]
        someWands = someWandsImport
    }
```

...
So the question is how do I properly parse this out.

Here's the segment that's giving me issues. The whole 'self used before all stored properties are initialized'

Comment: `@Binding` properties need to be initialized from some `@State` variable from another view (ie they need to be bound to them).  Are you sure `@Binding` is what you want? It's those `@State` variables that would be initialized from your global arrays.  If I understand your intent (and it's possible that I don't), moving those to an `ObservableObject` seems more inline with what you would need.

Comment: An example of code that uses `AccountView` might provide some clarity.

Comment: Thank you State was the solution. I knew it was something simple. My brain was a little fried at the time. Too much flip flopping between views or something.

Comment: I'm glad my comment somehow helped you solve your problem.  To be fair to your "fried" brain, property wrappers (and result builders) do make it a little too easy to think you know what code you wrote does without actually knowing.   Happens to me sometimes too.  They look like built-in parts of the language, but actually it's library code.  That's complicated by the fact that the compiler errors for their misuse, if you're lucky enough to get one,  aren't the most helpful.

Comment: For me it was helpful because I'm not the only one working on this. I had assumed my coworker had initialized the properties in a different view. Which I believe he did before we gave the views an overhaul. And you are so right, I was lucky to get a compiler error that helped. And your comment.

Answer (score 0):

When we work with struct it isn´t mandatory to add an initializer because a struct has one for default. I leave an example.

```
struct MyClassB {

    @Binding var count: Int
    
    func executeJob() {
        print(count)
    }
}

struct MyClassA {
    
    @State var count: Int = 0
    
    func doSomethingA() {
        let demoClass = MyClassB(count: $count)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This isn't directly related as I'm dealing with a custom class not a struct. Either way the solution was simple. Use State in the parent view. Binding in the children and Boom everything's flowing right. I was working with some peripherals and it wasn't clear where the these objects were being instanced. Many thanks to Chip Jarred for spotting it.